# How to migrate from Sqlite to Couchbase?

Tags: sqlite, couchbase, data-migration, couchbase-lite

I have a database in **Sqlite** and i want all the data from it to be migrated to my **Couchbase** Bucket. Is there any tool or easy method for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to export your relational data to a commma separated value (csv) file and import them into Couchbase via the `cbtransfer` tool described in http://www.couchbase.com/binaries/content/assets/us/product/couchbase-server-4.0/moving_from_relational_to_nosql_couchbase_2016.pdf.

The more realistic answer is: You'll need to write an algorithm to do the migration yourself. The reason for using Couchbase should not be to use your relational tables as they are, but to design some more complex data structures, using arrays and nested data, thereby getting rid of some of the tables and joins of the relational model. The mapping from relational to CB is then specific for your database design and can only be realized by an algorithm of your own. But as you'll need access methods for both the relational and the CB database anyway, this shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: This [document](http://www.couchbase.com/binaries/content/assets/us/product/couchbase-server-4.0/moving_from_relational_to_nosql_couchbase_2016.pdf.) is really awesome. Thanks for the help I have written my own migration script in Python.